# Stop Spring from creating "Whitelabel Error Page" depending on Accept header

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with a REST api which produces JSON responses. For handling errors, the controllers define an ExceptionHandler using `response.sendError`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyApiException.class)
public void handleControllerException(MyApiException ex,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(ex.getStatus().value(), ex.getResponseMessage());
}
```

This usually results in a JSON error response such as this:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-01-30T11:22:33.456Z", "status":400, "error":"Bad Request",
"message":"No customer with ID 123 found", "path":"/my/api/endpoint"}
```

But if the client sends an Accept header indicating it supports html, such as `text/html` or similar, Spring falls back to a HTML error page (represented as plain text here):

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Jan 30 11:22:33 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
No customer with ID 123 found
```

How do I get Spring to disable this behaviour and always respond with JSON instead? I've found a few general ways of overriding or disabling the Spring error page, but this seemed to be rather complex and usually aimed at providing a customized error page. This is only a minor annoyance during manual debugging with a browser (the actual clients don't send the offending Accept header) so I cannot justify big changes to the application. Is there a simple way to stop Spring from switching to an HTML error page depending on the Accept header?

Comment: Are you use @RestController annotation?

Comment: @Pavlo yes, the controller classes are annotated with `@RestController`

Answer (score 1):

Add `@ResponseBody` annotation and response object to the `handleControllerException` method`.
Your method would look something like this

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(MyApiException.class)
public ErrorModel handleControllerException(MyApiException ex,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    final int status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value();
    // Or any other status
    response.setStatus(status);

    final ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel();
    errorModel.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return errorModel;
}
```

Comment: That's a workaround, but then I'm just supplying my own response object. Ideally I would want something that works with `setError`... If that's not possible I might use this.

Comment: Why do you think it is a workaround? From my point of view it is recommended to create custom error models for different types of errors. i.e.  ValidationModel with full list of FieldErrors for 422 status and other models for other error cases. With this approach you are much more flexible and can provide more advanced and informative error response for your API

Comment: Yeah, the approach is more flexible but I don't need this flexibility as the error representation will not change. All I need is a way to stop Spring from being too smart for its own good. This is why I called it a workaround, it solves the problem by simply not using the thing which causes the current problem :) But as this is only an issue during manual testing, I'm looking for a minimal change, and while rewriting my controllers to use a custom response entity instead of calling setError isn't much effort It's not as minimal as I would have liked.

Comment: @l4mpi Years later.. did you find a better alternative :-)?

Comment: @Teddy tbh I don't even remember the specific project where I encountered this issue. Might be that we simply ignored it as it was only an inconvenience while testing, not a business requirement. If we found any simple workaround or fix I've forgotten it.